# SQL LIKE not functioning with space after query

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to make search functionality to output all available books based on author/title or genre typed in a form (I'm using sqlite), using LIKE function.

The piece of code I'm using is as follows:

```
# User reached route via POST (submitting the form)
else:
    query = request.form.get("query")

    # Ensure query is not blank
    if not query:
        return apology("you haven't typed anything!", 400)

    # Implementing search
    books = db.execute("SELECT author, title, genre, id FROM books WHERE booked = 0 AND (author LIKE '%' || :query || '%' OR title LIKE '%' || :query || '%' OR genre LIKE '%' || :query || '%')",
                      query = query)
```

However, users often type query followed by a space (especially on mobile devices). And in this case the code doesn't work.

1. How can I account for the **situation with a space after the query** and fix this?
2. Is it possible to account for infinite number of spaces? E.g. if I print 2 spaces after?

Thanks!

Comment: Use strip(): `query = request.form.get("query").strip()` to remove any leading or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want white space at either end of the query, you can trim the input:

```
query = request.form.get("query").strip();
```

This also makes sure `if not query` part is executed when the query consists solely of white space.